# Undefined method `router_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailgun, slim-lang, devise-recoverable

I am trying to send forgot password instruction via email and my slim template for email body contains below line

```
= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_url('@user.reset_password_token', email: @user.email)
```

And its showing error while sending mail.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
edit_user_password_url(reset_password_token: @user.reset_password_token, email: @user.email)
```

`edit_password_url` is really devise helper, not router http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/UrlHelpers